# How align dropdown of input datetime-local

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a issue (I guess) with bootstrap/material. I try to align the dropdown icon of `input` `datetime-local`.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group form-group-dtstart">
        <label class="control-label" for="dtstart">Execução *</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="dtstart" type="datetime-local" required>
        <span class="help-block hidden"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: code please....

Comment: ops... my bad...added

Answer (score 0):

Use these properties I think it's useful for you.

```
.icon-right {
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  position: relative;
}
```

else particular class name and write the properties.

```
class name {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```